# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process while deleting image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete original image after thumbnail create but original image cannot be deleted. It throws the exception

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Here is my code

```
public static string deleteImage(string imagename,string rootpath)
{
   try
   {
      string completePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rootpath + "Images/") + imagename;
      if (File.Exists(completePath))
      {
         File.Delete(completePath);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       throw e;
   }
}
```

Any idea, I am using Visual Studio 2008, thanks

Comment: You question and Question title are misleading

Comment: What are you doing with that file before trying to delete it? If you are using it by another function and you will not use dispose on that file it will give you above exception.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your connection with particular file still exist.....You had to do a dispose on the connection and then it worked......I prefered to use using statement......

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is open while you delete the file. Or You have to check the rights of that folder that you access.